# Controlling order of arguments in init of derived class defined with attrs

Tags: python, python-attrs

In `attrs` the order of arguments of the generated `init` method is determined by the order of attribute definition in the class + MRO (a standard way to define a total order based on multiple inheritance relations). That's not good for my use case, but there doesn't seem to be any flexibility to it. Here is the use case:

I am using `attrs` to define some classes modeling graphical primitives. These primitives are related in that they all need data to work on and produce graphics with given height and width, which have a default. So at top level there is a class

```py
@attr.s
class BaseGraphics:
    data = attr.ib()
    height = attr.ib(default=300)
    width = attr.ib(default=400)
```

Derived from this there are three classes, `UnivariateGraphics`, `BivariateGraphics` and `MultivariateGraphics` that use one, two or more columns in `data` resp. Let me show one:

```py
@attr.s
class BivariateGraphics(BaseGraphics):
    x = attr.ib()
    y = attr.ib()
```

The univariate case has only `x` and the multivariate case as a single `columns` attribute. This fails because in MRO `x` and `y` come after `height` and `width` but `x` and `y` are mandatory whereas `height` and `width` are not. The exact error is

```
ValueError: No mandatory attributes allowed after an attribute with 
a default value or factory.  Attribute in question: 
Attribute(name='x', default=NOTHING, validator=None, repr=True, 
cmp=True, hash=None, init=True, metadata=mappingproxy({}), type=None, 
converter=None, kw_only=False)
```

I could make up a default for `x` and `y` like the first and second column but still the order would be wrong. For instance if wanted to write something like

```py
BivariateGraphics(iris_data, "petalWidth", "sepalWidth")
```

the second and third arguments would be construed as `height` and `width`, not `x` and `y`. I can prevent this error by making all attributes but `data` keyword-only, but I can't support this syntax. From reading several related issues, e.g. #38, it seems this is the recommended approach. Close, but no cigar.

Another workaround would be to add `height` and `width` to each derived class independently. This would be a violation of the DRY principle and would fail to express and enforce this commonality between classes. There are more than three classes, and it would get pretty nasty.

This is not just an "academic" question. I am using `attrs` in a package, `autosig`, to help define APIs consistently. This is used in turn in a statistical graphics package, `altair_recipes`, where the above situation actually occurs (well, in the next release when I need to add `height` and `width` to all graphical primitives).

I could file an issue with the devs, but since the main dev has jokingly  (?) threatened people who subclass with electroshock, I feel it's going to be futile. I'd be interested in a non-inheritance based solution that doesn't require DRY violations or boilerplate. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I decided to avoid using inheritance and replace it with a combinator that acts before classes are generated. To do this instead of the  class syntax I used `attr.make_class`, which accepts attributes as an `OrderdDict` and honors the order. Hence the above combinator is just a way to combine `OrderedDicts` with some convention to define the final order. Not sure this passes the workaround level to achieve answer status, but it got me moving.

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this, where you want to be able to rely on stable APIs (especially while subclassing where the order isn’t always clear on the first sight), we strongly recommend to use classmethod factories (and that’s also what I tend to use in my own code). Whenever you start changing things around in your classes, things can get messy especially if you have to navigate multiple hierarchies. Therefore it’s better to build APIs on your own terms and use attrs only for plumbing.

> but since the main dev has jokingly (?) threatened people who subclass with electroshock

While I do have a rather strong stance on subclassing, I have problems to imagine to be on record of threatening anyone else than myself with electroshocks unless it was banter under likeminded friends. If I indeed had such a slip of judgement, I apologize.

Comment: I can't find the electroshock quote, so maybe it was an error, my turn to apologize. But if I can remember, it was funny and not threatening at all.  I will think about the classmethod approach and how it can apply to my use case, thanks.

Comment: @hynek - can you please add an example of such use of "classmethod factories"

Comment: The init docs have an example: https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/init.html